# velocity.ui intermittently fails with the error "Velocity UI Pack: velocity must be loaded first."

Tags: jquery, requirejs, amd, velocity.js

When I load `velocity.ui`, I get an intermittent error on the console:

```
Velocity UI Pack: Velocity must be loaded first. Aborting.
```

and none of `velocity.ui`'s animations are available.

I can reproduce the issue with something as simple as this:

```
<script>
require.config({
  baseUrl: "/static/lib/",
  paths: {
    jquery: "external/jquery",
    velocity: "external/velocity/velocity.min",
    "velocity.ui": "external/velocity/velocity.ui.min",
  }
});

require(["jquery", "velocity.ui"]);
</script>
```

When I look at the network requests, I see that `velocity` *has* loaded before `velocity.ui`. And `velocity.ui` does have `define(["velocity"], ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

If your project uses jQuery *at all, for any reason,* then you must make `velocity` dependent on the `jquery` module. Otherwise, you'll run into the problem you ran into. Create a module called `velocity-glue`:

```
define(['velocity', 'jquery'], function (velocity) {
  return velocity;
});
```

Modify your configuration so that it contains these two entries.

```
map: {
  "*": {
    velocity: "velocity-glue",
  },
  "velocity-glue": {
    velocity: "velocity",
  },
}
```

The first entry makes it so that `velocity-glue` is used whenever `velocity` is required. The second entry makes sure that `velocity-glue` can get the original `velocity`.

#### Explanation

I'm going to use "Velocity" to refer to the product globally: this includes both modules (`velocity` and `velocity-ui`).

The problem is that Velocity is not a good AMD citizen. By this, I mean that its modules depend on globals and export themselves as globals, *even when they are loaded through an AMD loader*, which is bad behavior for AMD modules.

**Velocity can be used with or without jQuery.** When Velocity is used without jQuery, it uses a kind of minimal polyfill that provides only as much of jQuery's functions as Velocity needs. Since Velocity can be used with or without jQuery, its modules not **not** list jQuery in their dependencies when they call `define`, otherwise, they would require you to use jQuery.

Whether or not Velocity is loaded as an AMD module, it installs itself so that it will be accessible as the `Velocity` property on one of these if they existr: `window.jQuery` `window.Zepto`, or `window`. Velocity will use the first one that it can use in the order given here. So if neither jQuery nor Zepto are installed, it will be accessible as `window.Velocity`. But if jQuery is installed, it will be accessible as `window.jQuery.Velocity`.  The problem is that both `velocity` and `velocity.ui` perform the computation choosing between the 3 possible locations **independently**. Let's consider some scenarios:

Scenario A:

1. `jquery` loads.
2. `velocity` installs as `window.jQuery.Velocity`.
3. `velocity.ui` looks for `window.jQuery.Velocity`. Fine.

Scenario B:

[`jquery` is not loaded yet.]

1. `velocity` installs as `window.Velocity`.
2. `velocity.ui` looks for `window.Velocity`. Fine.

(`jquery` may or may not load later. It does not matter.)

Scenario C:

1. `velocity` installs itself as `window.Velocity` because jQuery is not loaded.
2. `jquery` loads.
3. `velocity.ui` looks for `window.jQuery.Velocity` because `window.jQuery` does exist, but `window.jQuery.Velocity` does not exist! **You get an error**.

Note that in the scenarios above `velocity` will *always* load before `velocity.ui` because `velocity.ui` lists `velocity` as its dependency. However, the loading order of jQuery relative to the two other modules is not constrained because (as already mentioned) they do not depend on `jquery`.

The solution I've given in the first section to this answer fixes the issue by constraining the load order: `jquery` will always load before both modules.

Comment: attempting to use your solution, but I'm still receiving:

Velocity UI Pack: Velocity must be loaded first. Aborting.
when I require 'velocity' should i be requring 'velocity-glue' instead?

Comment: What I'm showing in this answer has been used in production for months. Make sure you don't have a typo anywhere because that can silently make the whole thing fail. (One way to check this is to look at the network requests: `velocity-glue` should load, and it should load before `velocity` and `velocity.ui`.) Regarding the question you added to your comment: no, you should be requiring `velocity`. The whole point of the `map` setting is so that the glue is invisible to the rest of your application.